# UISlider does not redraw automatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uislider

I've an UISlider on my app and I need sometimes to update not only its value but also its minimumValue. The values are changed but if I call the setValue method or assign a new value for my slider, it has the new value but the slider does not repaint itself to the position it should be for this new value. How can I repaint it? 
This is a piece of code where I change the minimumValue.

```
if([array count] < 50)
    [sliderTamanyo setMinimumValue:2];
else if([array count] < 200)
    [sliderTamanyo setMinimumValue:3];
else
    [sliderTamanyo setMinimumValue:4];
if(sliderTamanyo.value < sliderTamanyo.minimumValue)
     self.sliderTamanyo.value = self.sliderTamanyo.minimumValue;     
[self.sliderTamanyo setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: setValue should do that, I guess problem is that you change its minimumValue on the fly, but who knows without code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved that by removing and adding again the slider to the toolbar. I've used this code:

```
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.toolbar.items];
id slider = [items lastObject]; 
[items removeLastObject];
self.toolbar.items = items;    
[items addObject:slider];
self.toolbar.items = items;
```

I've recovered my slider using an `id` instead an `UISlider` because that slider is inside a `UIBarButtonItem`

Answer (score 2):

As `UISlider` inherits from `UIView` can you not just call `[yourSlider setNeedsDisplay];` after you've updated the values.

This will force the `UISlider` instance to completely redraw itself and may therefore take into account the new values you've set.

EDIT:

There seems to be some common issues when embedding a `UISlider` in a `UIBarButtonItem` - please see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771241/uislider-in-uibarbuttonitem-impacts-animation-behavior) for more information.

Comment: I've used: 
    [self.sliderTamanyo setValue:4 animated:YES];
    [self.sliderTamanyo setNeedsDisplay];
But it's still not working...

Comment: Is your slider created in code, or via IB. If it's via IB are you sure all your outlets are hooked up properly?

Comment: I've created it using IB. I've checked it and its referencing outlet is correctly hooked but I've seen that my slider is inside an UIBarButton because I've added the slider into a toolbar

Comment: The fact its embedded inside a `UIBarbuttonItem` may be the source of your problems. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771241/uislider-in-uibarbuttonitem-impacts-animation-behavior) Stack Overflow question & related answers

Comment: I've still the same problem. I've included some code where I change the minimum value of the slider and I use the setNeedsDisplay method

Comment: Yes, I've tried to get out of the toolbar the slider so that it's no more inside a `UIBarButtonItem` . The only thing I haven't tried yet is to use a view instead of a toolbar (I would like to avoid that)

Comment: I you are really intent on having it appear as thought the `UISlider` is embedded in a `UIToolbar` then you may not be able to avoid it. I've done a fair bit of searching (*hate having a question beat me*) and the solution in the link I posted is the only reasonable, workable solution I've come across.

Comment: I've solved my problem. It's not the best way to solve it but it works and it's enough for this project. What I've done to solve this is: 1.- Remove the slider from the toolbar. 2.- Add it again. I'm going to post my own answer so that anybody can use it if having the same issue. Thanx for helping!